# how products should be automatically ported to facebook in php

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

How all of my products should be automatically ported to facebook at the time of adding to the website. When a car is sold out and we change status from Available/Reserved to Sold, this should reflect on the facebook as well. my site is in php.Thanks in an advance.